# Show that the identity permutation cannot be expressed as the product of an odd number of transpositions.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, symmetric-groups

> Show that the identity permutation cannot be expressed as the product of an odd number of transpositions.

For example consider the example of $S_3,$ $\sigma_{id} = (123)(321) = (1 2) (13)(32)(31)$, which means even number of permutations.

In general let $\sigma_{id}= \sigma_1.\sigma_1\cdots \sigma_k $, I need to show if I rewrite each $\sigma_i$ as transpositions then 
odd number of transpositions will be there.

Thank You.

Comment: IMHO, the simplest proof (one of the answers in the reference given upwards, but not selected as "the" answer) is by using the **signature** function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prove that if $\sigma\in S_n$ is a product of $r$ transpositions, and has $s$ cycles, then $r+s+n\equiv 0\pmod 2$.

Comment: could you elaborate little more how it will prove the original statement

Comment: @babai The identity permutation has $n$ cycles.